# How to switch users on Microsoft MobileServiceClient with Google authentication

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I have an Xamarin Android app that uses an Azure MobileServiceClient (DataService.client).  It is set up to use Google authentication.  I log in as follows:

```
          var user = await DataService.client.LoginAsync(this,
                MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Google, "myapp");
```

This works great.  It opens a browser to the Google Login page and you log in.  Once you do this one time on your android device, it no longer prompts you for login information.  I have a situation where I want to log in as a different user to test some internal app permissions.  I created a logout function as follows:

```
        await DataService.client.LogoutAsync();
```

This logs you out, but the next time you need to authenticate, it doesn't prompt you for credentials.  It logs you right back in as the same person.  Is there a way to clear the login information so it will ask for your username again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `MobileServiceClient.LogoutAsync()` just clears the `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser` for the current MobileServiceClient instance in your mobile client. In order to completely login out, you need to manually send a sign out request to your mobile backend as follows before you execute `MobileServiceClient.LogoutAsync()`.

```
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout
Header X-ZUMO-AUTH:{MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken}
```

Details you could follow adrian hall's book about [Implementing a LogoutAsync() method](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/realworld/#implementing-a-logoutasync-method).

Comment: I will give this a shot.  Thanks!